# Make it possible to use imports of the whole project in the catalog CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, imgui

I want to make a small application using imgui

To run the test window I use the opengl glfw backend

The problem is that the files in the lib/ imgui_gl directory of my project can't access the headers that the file at the root of the project has access to

[image: CMake problem]

This is what my CmakeList file looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(boardserver)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(LIB_FOLDER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) # Lib folder


add_executable(boardserver main.cpp)

find_package(imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

## Imgui opengl glfw backend lib
set(imgui-gl_Includes "${LIB_FOLDER}/imgui_gl/")
add_library(imgui-gl STATIC
        ${LIB_FOLDER}/imgui_gl/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp ${LIB_FOLDER}/imgui_gl/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp )


include_directories(${imgui-gl_Includes})
target_link_libraries(boardserver PRIVATE imgui::imgui GLEW::GLEW OpenGL::GL SDL2::SDL2 glfw imgui-gl)
```

Comment: Unrelated: don't use the "naked" `link_libraries` or `include_directories`. Always use the `target_*` forms to make it explicit which target sees what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell CMake to link `imgui-gl` with the `imgui::imgui` target so it knows where to find imgui.h too:

```
target_link_libraries(imgui-gl PUBLIC imgui::imgui)
```

As modern CMake best practice, you may also want to make its include directory part of the interface:

```
target_include_directories(imgui-gl PUBLIC "${LIB_FOLDER}/imgui_gl")
```

Together, these statements ensure that any target that links to `imgui-gl` sees both the correct headers and knows what to link to.

Comment: Thx! So much u help me!